# How do I trigger a tapped event (on a map pin) without using callouts?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to trigger a tapped event (on a map pin) without the use of callouts?

I tried to implement the didSelectAnnotationView below, but it did not seem to work:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if let annotation = annotation {
        let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = false
            view.enabled = true
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil


}


 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    println("test")

}
```

Comment: `didSelectAnnotationView` is the right way to do it. Are you sure that your map's delegate has been set up? Is your `viewForAnnotation` actually getting called? (Add log/breakpoint there to make sure.)

Comment: Hi Rob, yes, my viewForAnnotation wasn't called. I've set my mapview delegate and the code is working fine now. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `didSelectAnnotationView` is the correct method. If you're not seeing it called, it's likely that the map view's `delegate` has not been set.

The default `viewForAnnotation` behavior will render something very close to what yours does, so it might not be immediately obvious that the `delegate` wasn't set properly. You might want to put a log/breakpoint in `viewForAnnotation` (or do something that makes it more visually distinct, e.g. different pin color) and confirm whether the delegate methods are getting called at all.